# Creation of Another ItemTemplate in MetroApps?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, winjs

[image]Can I create another ItemTemplate in MetroApp.Here Iam using visual-studio2012RC and Windows8 for developing metro application.I was using the following code .It is working fine, as the same way i want to create another ItemTemplate for adding some data to my application,Is there any other template instead of this or again can we use this in our Html?
Can anyone suggest me.

Working examples are really helpful to me.

Thank u in advance.

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title"/>
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
        <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question? Do you mean "can I define a second template"? Yes. Or do you mean "can I render the template somewhere else"? Or... I just don't get it.

Comment: @ Chris Tavares,Here i hav given my application-scenario.In this app i do not want to use any image for Group-2 and Group-3 items.But if i remove image-tag in above code,It is effecting on Group-1.So is there any other way to maintain Each group information separately or can i create another item-template for my problem?Can u give me any working example?Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign two item templates, but you can assign JS function which generates item template dynamically depending on content you want to bind. Check MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700705.aspx#using_a_function_to_display_items

In your case just check if image url is empty and don't render "item-image" element.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thnak u Agnius,if i give image url empty it is showing like empty spacein the place of image,so what should i do?

Comment: My idea was **not to render** img element at all if url is empty. You would skip it in render function like that:
`if (item.data.picture) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = item.data.picture;
div.appendChild(img);
}`
Of course code depends on data structure and whether you use jQuery or not, but the idea should be clear. I hope :)